# Accounts Library: AccountInfoCommand doesn't have an Update command

Tags: corda

1. `AccountInfo` state has a field called `status` which is initialized with the value `ACTIVE`, but currently `AccountInfoCommand` class only has one command which is `Create`, so should we use that if we want to write a flow that deactivates an account (i.e. updates it, not creates it)? I don't feel that's right since there should be certain checks that are related to an update command (like there should be one input and one output with same linearId, etc...).
2. Is there a reason why `RequestAccountFlow` was designed to return an `AccountInfo` as opposed to StateAndRef? The latter makes it easier to request an `AccountInfo`; then use it as an input for a certain transaction (like in my case, I would request an account, get its StateAndRef, clone it with the new status, use the StateAndRef as input, and the clone with new status as output).

Answer (score 0):

With the current Accounts implementation, `the AccountInfo` state no longer has the status state. https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/states/AccountInfo.kt

And the `RequestAccountFlow` was coded in a way to utilizing `ShareAccountInfoFlow` (which returns an `AccountInfo`)